# C# MVC insufficient __RequestVerificationToken cookie regeneration

Tags: owin, xss, session-cookies, antiforgerytoken

We are using C# MVC with Entity Framework and custom authentication implementing OWIN to make authentiation available by a custom user database.
Users login and authenticate themself by username and password by a standard login form.

To fit common security messurements OWIN regenerates the ".AspNet.ApplicationCookie" on each login and logout, I also force the "SessionIDManager" to regenerate a new Session ID (saved in .AspNet.ApplicationCookie) on each authentication change.

We use QUALYS to test the application for well known attack scenarios such as XSS, Session Hijacking etc. One imortant technic is to issue and validate Antiforgey Token which will be placed inside the form field AND inside a cookie stored on the client. As I unterstood these do not have to match since they are encrypted and get verified after decrypted on serverside on POST request (with ValidateAntiForgeryToken Attribute).

As mentioned above we use QUALYS to cover possible vulnerability scenarios. The report mentioned a security issue with the "__RequestVerifiationToken" which is set in the cookie and will not be regenerated until it gets invalidated by time. I reproduced this by tracking the traffic with Fiddler.

So the Token are there, get verified and I can log in, log out, chagne password and so on.

My question is, is there a build in possibility to reissue a __RequestVerifiationToken for the cookie?
When using the HtmlHelper @Html.AntiForgeryToken() it regerenates a new token for the hidden form field on each reload, but the cookie value keeps the same over time. I need to regerenate the cookie __RequestVerifiationToken value as well, at least on login / logout actions.

A side question is why internet explorer (Edge) requests result in a long time request when I manipulate the hidden form field content, firefox instead gets the error that a AntiForgery Erros occured?

Comment: Did you find a way of doing this?